# VBA Access form doesn't show

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm developing an application in MS Access, using VBA.

The application already exists but I have to add a button and a piece of code in a form.

The problem is that, when I add the button and try to show the form, I don't receive an error but the form isn't visible.

I'm sure that the form is open, because, if I try to delete it, I receive an error that tells me that is not possible to delete an opened form.

Can anyone tells me the solution?

*Edit*: I still have the same problem on another form in my application. The form worked since i add a piece of code in it. Now, also deleting the code it doesn't work... I've also tried to decompile the application but nothing changed...

Comment: Try decompiling and compact and repair. Is it a popup form? Maybe it appears on the other monitor? Maybe it is open in design view? I'm guessing this is something banal you are overlooking. Take a break and try again in 30 minutes. :)

Comment: I've tried to decompile the application and now it's working. I did not know this function. Thank you very much!

Comment: I still have the same problem on another form in my application. The form worked since i add a piece of code in it.
Now, also deleting the code it doesn't work... I've also tried to decompile the application but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

The following function has several arguments for show/hide etc. With the correct parameters you should be able to get that form to be visible:

```
OpenForm(FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode, OpenArgs)
```

All the argument options can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx).